# Can figure out how to get wordpress to go .com not .com/directory

Tags: installation

hey I just installed wordpress and everything is working fine but when I go to www.domain.com nothing shows up it only works when I go to www.domain.com/directory

anyone know how to change this?

I've tried googling it but I can't figure out how to "phrase" it to google, lol.

thanks.

Comment: Where is WordPress installed on your server, in the document root or in `/directory`? What is **site address** set to?

Comment: Try: http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory#Using_a_pre-existing_subdirectory_install

Answer (score 0):

try

Install WordPress in a subdirectory, such as /2012.
In your root folder (not the subdirectory folder), download and open your .htaccess file.
Add the following to your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?YourDomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ blog [L]
```

In the above code, change the "YourDomain.com" value to your root domain.
In the above code, change the "blog" value to the subdirectory.
Save and upload the .htacess file back to your root directory.